# LabelEncoder for two DataFrames

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm really struggling with encoding categorical types. Given two DataFrames `X_train` and `X_test` I'm trying to encode all the zip codes. The greatest hindrance for me is to be able to encode values from **both** dataframes (as they vary to some extention) in the same fashion, so I thought of making a list of all possible zip code values and then use it to encode both series (as parts of DataFrames). Unfortunately, this doesn't work as an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'transform'` appears. I'm running out of ideas.

```
X_train = X[['ticket_id','judgment_amount','zip_code']]
X_test = y[['ticket_id','judgment_amount','zip_code']]


Xtrain_zipcode =  X_train['zip_code'].dropna().unique().tolist()
Xtest_zipcode = X_test['zip_code'].dropna().unique().tolist()

zip_list = Xtrain_zip

for elem in Xtest_zipcode:
    if elem not in Xtrain_zipcode:
        zip_list.append(elem)

enc_zipc = LabelEncoder().fit(zip_list)
encoded = enc_zipc.transform(zip_list)
encoded.transform(X_train['zip_code'])
```

I have also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217713/labelencoder-for-categorical-features) that `LabelEncoder` is not advisable while dealing with categorical features that are an input. What would you suggest? One-hot encoding?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to concatenate train and test and then fit the encoder on the concatenated zip?

```
X_train = X[['ticket_id','judgment_amount','zip_code']]
X_test = y[['ticket_id','judgment_amount','zip_code']]
X_train['zip_code'] = X_train['zip_code'].astype(str)
X_test['zip_code'] = X_test['zip_code'].astype(str)

concat = pd.concat([X_train, X_test], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

enc_zipc = LabelEncoder()
enc_zipc.fit(concat['zip_code'])

X_train['zip_code'] = enc_zipc.transform(X_train['zip_code'])
X_test['zip_code'] = enc_zipc.transform(X_test['zip_code'])
```