# is there a way to lable encode comma sepearated values in single column..?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-processing, label-encoding

I have this column containing multiple values..:

[image]

I want to preprocess this by label encoding it, how can I proceed further?
i don't want one hot encode it. cause it is for classification problem

Comment: You shouldn't use LabelEncoder for the features, see [LabelEncoder for categorical features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217713/labelencoder-for-categorical-features/61217936#61217936). *i don't want one hot encode it. cause it is for classification problem*, what makes you think that OneHotEncoder is not suited for classification problems?

Comment: I didn't get your question. One-hot-encoding is just a way of feature representation. It doesn't depend on your final task (whether its regression or classification. One-hot-encoding will be suitable for you. As @yatu mentioned above, LabelEncoder gives an effect of ordering and model try to capture that order as a relation in the data. So we we usually avoid LabelEncoding.

Comment: so if i use one hot encoding how could I one hot encode the labels..? because my labels consist of -----> [ARTS,SPORTS,ACADEMICS]