# Use same Label Encoder for train and test dataframes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I have 2 different csv which has a train data and test data. I created two different dataframes from these train_features_df and test_features_df. Note that the test and train data have multiple categorical columns, so i need to apply labelEncoder on them as it is suitable as for my dataset. So i had separately applied label encoder on train and test data. When i print the new encoded value of train and test dataset i see for the same categorical value of same feature the output from new encoded data is different. Does that mean i have to merge the train and test data. Then apply label encoding and then seperate them back again ?

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
 target=train_features_df['y']
 train_features_df=train_features_df.drop(['y'], axis=1)
 train_features_df.head()
 y = target.values
 print("printing feature column of train datasets: \n")
 print(train_features_df.values)
 le=LabelEncoder()
 X_train_label_encoded=train_features_df.apply(le.fit_transform)
 print("\n printing feature column of train datasets after label encoder: \n")
 print(X_train_label_encoded.head())

 print("printing test feature datasets: \n")
 print(test_features_df)
 X_test_label_encoded=test_features_df.apply(le.fit_transform)
 print("printing test feature encoded  datasets: \n")
 print(X_test_label_encoded)
```

Output of above is below:-

```
printing feature column of train datasets: 

[['k' 'v' 'at' ... 0 0 0]
 ['k' 't' 'av' ... 0 0 0]
 ['az' 'w' 'n' ... 0 0 0]

    X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8  X10  X12  ...  X375  X376  X377  X378  \
 0  32  23  17   0   3  24   9  14    0    0  ...     0     0     1     0   
 1  32  21  19   4   3  28  11  14    0    0  ...     1     0     0     0   
 2  20  24  34   2   3  27   9  23    0    0  ...     0     0     0     0

 printing test feature datasets: 

       X0  X1  X2 X3 X4  X5 X6 X8  X10  X12  ...  X375  X376  X377  X378  X379  \
 0     az   v   n  f  d   t  a  w    0    0  ...     0     0     0     1     0   
 1      t   b  ai  a  d   b  g  y    0    0  ...     0     0     1     0     0   
 2     az   v  as  f  d   a  j  j    0    0  ...     0     0     0     1     0

       X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8  X10  X12  ...  X375  X376  X377  X378  \
 0     21  23  34   5   3  26   0  22    0    0  ...     0     0     0     1   
 1     42   3   8   0   3   9   6  24    0    0  ...     0     0     1     0   
 2     21  23  17   5   3   0   9   9    0    0  ...     0     0     0     1   
 3     21  13  34   5   3  31  11  13    0    0  ...     0     0     0     1   
 4     45  20  17   2   3  30   8  12    0    0  ...     1     0     0     0
```

If we see in train dataframe after lebel encoding the `az` value in first column got transformed to value 20 while in test dataframe after lebel encoding the `az` value in first column got transformed to value 21.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that the unique values appearing in the training and the test sets are different. And in that case, the encodings will be different too.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform([1,2,3,4,5])
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
le.fit_transform([2,3,4,5])
# array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

You should be fitting with the train data, and then `transform` on the test data to get the same encodings:

```
l_train = [1,2,3,4,5]
le.fit(l_train)
le.transform(l_train)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
le.transform([2,3,4,5])
#array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Do note though that you should not be using a label encoder for the categorical features. See [LabelEncoder for categorical features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217713/labelencoder-for-categorical-features/61217936#61217936) for an explanation of why. `LabelEncoder` should only be used on the label. You should be looking at `OneHotEncoder` for instance.

Comment: in this case how do and where do i see a final dataframe with all columns with finally encoded value ? I tried doing below and got the error  y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (4209, 364) instead. does it not take the entire dataframe ?
le=LabelEncoder()
le.fit(train_features_df)
le.transform(train_features_df)

Comment: It expects a 1d array, because as I'm telling you, this is thought for the label column, i.e a síngle column, not multiple features @invictus

Comment: How about if the test sub-sample contains a label that doesn't appear in the train sub-sample? For example: l_train = [1,2,3,4,5] and l_test=[2,3,4,5,6]. The method above will throw an error because 6 is not in the train sub-sample. How do you solve it?