# Using a LabelEncoder in sklearn's Pipeline gives: fit_transform takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I've been trying to run some ML code but I keep faltering at the fitting stage after running my pipeline. I've looked around on various forums to not much avail. What I've discovered is that some people say you can't use LabelEncoder within a pipeline. I'm not sure how true that is. If anyone has any insights on the matter I'd be very happy to hear them.

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

And so I'm not sure if the problem is from me or from python. Here's my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("ks-projects-201801.csv",
                   index_col="ID",
                   parse_dates=["deadline","launched"],
                   infer_datetime_format=True)

var = list(data)

data = data.drop(labels=[1014746686,1245461087, 1384087152, 1480763647, 330942060, 462917959, 69489148])
missing = [i for i in var if data[i].isnull().any()]
data = data.dropna(subset=missing,axis=0)
le = LabelEncoder()
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
oh = OneHotEncoder()
y = [i for i in var if i=="state"]
y = data[var.pop(8)]

p,p.index = pd.Series(le.fit_transform(y)),y.index
q = pd.read_csv("y.csv",index_col="ID")["0"]
label_y = le.fit_transform(y)

x = data[var]

obj_feat = x.select_dtypes(include="object")
dat_feat = x.select_dtypes(include="datetime64[ns]")
dat_feat = dat_feat.assign(dmonth=dat_feat.deadline.dt.month.astype("int64"),
                           dyear = dat_feat.deadline.dt.year.astype("int64"),
                           lmonth=dat_feat.launched.dt.month.astype("int64"),
                           lyear=dat_feat.launched.dt.year.astype("int64"))
dat_feat = dat_feat.drop(labels=["deadline","launched"],axis=1)
num_feat = x.select_dtypes(include=["int64","float64"])

u = dict(zip(list(obj_feat),[len(obj_feat[i].unique()) for i in obj_feat]))
le_obj = [i for i in u if u[i]<10]
oh_obj = [i for i in u if u[i]<20 and u[i]>10]
te_obj = [i for i in u if u[i]>20 and u[i]<25]
cb_obj = [i for i in u if u[i]>100]

# Pipeline time
#Impute and encode

strat = ["constant","most_frequent","mean","median"]
sc = StandardScaler()
oh_unk = "ignore"
encoders = [LabelEncoder(),
            OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown=oh_unk),
            TargetEncoder(),
            CatBoostEncoder()]

#num_trans = Pipeline(steps=[("imp",SimpleImputer(strategy=strat[2])),
num_trans = Pipeline(steps=[("sc",sc)])
#obj_imp = Pipeline(steps=[("imp",SimpleImputer(strategy=strat[1]))])
oh_enc = Pipeline(steps=[("oh_enc",encoders[1])])
te_enc = Pipeline(steps=[("te_enc",encoders[2])])
cb_enc = Pipeline(steps=[("cb_enc",encoders[0])])

trans = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                                        ("num",num_trans,list(num_feat)+list(dat_feat)),
                                        #("obj",obj_imp,list(obj_feat)),
                                        ("onehot",oh_enc,oh_obj),
                                        ("target",te_enc,te_obj),
                                        ("catboost",cb_enc,cb_obj)
                                        ])

models = [RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0),
          KNeighborsClassifier(),
          DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)]

model = models[2]

print("Check 4")

# Chaining it all together
run = Pipeline(steps=[("Transformation",trans),("Model",model)])

x = pd.concat([obj_feat,dat_feat,num_feat],axis=1)
print("Check 5")
run.fit(x,p)
```

It runs fine until run.fit where it throws an error. I'd love to hear any advice anyone might have, and any possible ways to resolve this problem would also be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the same as spotted in [this answer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py#L243), but with a `LabelEncoder` in your case. The `LabelEncoder`'s [`fit_transform`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py#L243) method takes:

```
def fit_transform(self, y):
    """Fit label encoder and return encoded labels
    ...
```

Whereas `Pipeline` is expecting that all its transformers are taking three positional arguments `fit_transform(self, X, y)`.

You could make a custom transformer as in the aforementioned answer, however, a `LabelEncoder` *should not be used as a feature transformer*. An extensive explanation on why can be seen in [LabelEncoder for categorical features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217713/labelencoder-for-ordinal-features/61217936#61217936). So I'd recommend not using a `LabelEcoder` and using some other bayesian encoders if the amount of features gets too high such as the `TargetEncoder` which you also have in the list of encoders.

Comment: Thanks for this. I want to encode the target variable. Do you have any advice on how I'd go about that?